# Starting triton inference server docker container on kube cluster

Tags: python, kubernetes, nvidia-docker, inference-engine, tritonserver

**Description**
Trying to deploy the triton docker image as container on kubernetes cluster

**Triton Information**
What version of Triton are you using? -> 22.10

**Are you using the Triton container or did you build it yourself?**
I used the server repo with following command:

```
python3 compose.py --backend onnxruntime --backend python --backend tensorflow2 --repoagent checksum --container-version 22.10
```

then again created new triton image with following dockerfile:

```
FROM tritonserver:latest
RUN apt install python3-pip -y
RUN pip install tensorflow==2.7.0
RUN pip install transformers==2.11.0
RUN pip install tritonclient
RUN pip install tritonclient[all]
```

and dockerfile is being with following command:

```
docker build -t customtritonimage -f ./DockerFiles/DockerFile  .
```

**To Reproduce**
directory structure:
parent directory -> tritonnludeployment
files in it -> DockerFiles (folder containing docker files), k8_trial.yaml, model_repo_triton (all the models here in triton-supported directory shape and has required files)

I am using this 'k8_trial.yaml' file for starting kubectl deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: flower
    labels:
      app: flower
spec:
    replicas: 3
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: flower
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: flower
      spec:
        volumes:
        - name: models
          hostPath:
            # server: 216.48.183.17
            path: /root/Documents/tritonnludeployment
            # readOnly: false
            type: Directory
        containers:
          - name: flower
            ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
              name: http-triton
            - containerPort: 8001
              name: grpc-triton
            - containerPort: 8002
              name: metrics-triton
            image: "customtritonimage:latest"
            imagePullPolicy: Never
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /root/Documents/tritonnludeployment
              name: models
            command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
            args: ["cd /models /opt/tritonserver/bin/tritonserver --model-repository=/models/model_repo_triton --allow-gpu-metrics=false --strict-model-config=false"]
            # resources:
            #   requests:
            #     memory: "500Mi"
            #     cpu: "500Mi"
            #   limits:
            #     memory: "900Mi"
            #     cpu: "900Mi"
            #     nvidia.com/gpu: 1
```

Describe the models (framework, inputs, outputs), ideally include the model configuration file (if using an ensemble include the model configuration file for that as well).

**Expected behavior**
kubectl deployment should start, with triton container as one of the pods

Which step i am doing wrong!

Answer (score 1):

And what is the error message you are getting? Some of the issues I noticed:

- use the expected file name know to `docker`, i.e. `Dockerfile` not `DockerFile`
- make sure base image exists (`tritonserver:latest` does not, you probably want one of [these](https://catalog.ngc.nvidia.com/orgs/nvidia/containers/tritonserver/tags))
- first update the sources (`RUN apt install` ... -> `RUN apt update && apt install` ...)
- reduce layers number by installing multiple python packages at once
- `tritonclient[all]` already includes `tritonclient`
- don't run containers as `root` (`tritonserver` does not require it anyway)
- make sure you pull the image first time (`imagePullPolicy`: `Never` -> `IfNotPresent`)
- remove multiple and unnecessary commands from `args` (such as `cd /models`)
- `tritonserver` can import all subfolders, so `--model-repository=/models` is probably better

Comment: thanks, i got the issue solved as it was more of a k8 installation based issue but will keep these as well in mind :)